# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress

I got an issue with this on my local server. The issue is not due to the jetpack plugin because I have already deleted it

`C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 284`

`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in post-template.php on line 284`

Please, anyone, help me with this issue.

Comment: Consider adding some more details

Comment: @RaulRene this is nothing wrong with the custom code the error is from WordPress I have tried installing the latest version of WordPress but nothing changes. and I have also tried uninstalling the plugins but the warning does not goes away

Answer (score 7):

Did you put the_content() in loop if not

Here try this :

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <article class="post">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p> 
    </article>
    <?php 
} // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be caused by use of get_the_excerpt, get_the_content or similar functions outside of The Loop (in custom context, somewhere in theme's functions.php etc).

Add **setup_postdata** before. That fills the global variable $pages. Otherwise PHP7.2+ will output a warning in post-template.php on line 284.

For example:

```
global $post;
setup_postdata($post);
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post);
```

See [setup_postdata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/), [get_the_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) and [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is comming from using the_content or get_the_content in PHP 7.2+ as those function have a check for the global page which can be null. 
In 7.2 null is not a valid value for countable and this is what trows the error a workarround for this is pulling the content diretly from the meta fields. Code below, more info can be found in this video I made https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMguTNzFoUk (The TLDR section is after the middle of the video I guess, the first one is just a snippet placement explanation)

```
apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post->id));
```